# Freeglut fgInitGL2: fghGenBuffers is NULL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glew, freeglut

On the glutCreateWindow this message appears - what can cause such problem?

Here the code that i have:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "include/glew.h"
#include "include/glut.h"
#include "include/freeglut.h"
#include "Mathematics.h"

GLuint VBO;

static void RenderSceneCB()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 1);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}


static void InitializeGlutCallbacks()
{
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderSceneCB);
}

static void CreateVertexBuffer()
{
    Vector3f Vertices[1];
    Vertices[0] = Vector3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(1024, 768);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("My");

    // Must be done after glut is initialized!
    GLenum res = glewInit();
    if (res != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: '%s'\n", glewGetErrorString(res));
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("Glew Inited");
    }

    InitializeGlutCallbacks();

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    CreateVertexBuffer();

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem, and i found this answer

> It took me some time, but the cause of the problem was in the
>   hardware. I was running on a virtual machine (VMware) and although the
>   specifications said that it supported OpenGL up to 2.1 I found out
>   that it doesn't support OpenGL at all.
>
> My solution was to take an old machine, install Windows on it, and
>   copy all files. It compiled and runs as smooth as a can.
>
> If anyone else runs into the same problem I can advise to get it
>   working on a native installation before virtualising. It can safe you
>   a lot of time.

by [martinvb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/655158/martinvb)

as fare as i know it's an hardware.